# How do I sort Labels on SSRS Line chart's value (Y) axis?

Tags: reporting-services

[SSRS Line Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZjIZ.png)

Please see the attached image, how do I sort the value axis of an SSRS line chart? i.e in ascending order e.g 10,20,30,40 rather than 40,30,20,10 (SSRS default sort order). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

"Vertical Axis Properties" -> "Axis Options" -> "Scale options" -> "Reverse directions"

And also for keeping the labels at the bottom.

"Series Properties" -> "Axes and Chart Area" -> "Change series axis position" -> "Horizontal axis" select "Secondary"

Comment: Thanks Serkan, but that flips the chart,I still need the X - axis labels to be at the bottom of the chart.

Comment: I made an update for keeping the labels at the bottom.